# Using Google Maps API Javascript v3 with phonegap

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have a public developer API key and my company has a Enterprise API key.
We are trying to make our phonegap app load the javascript api with one of this keys.

API loads fine when called without the key:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true
```

But google's tutorial says that although calling without key still works, it is not recommended anymore.

When I use clientid or API KEY I am facing the below mentioned error "Google has disabled Maps API for this application....". As per maps documentation we need to register callers domaian/url. As I am using maps in hybrid android app, It is not clear what i need to do. I see that in request "android-assets/www/xxx" goes to server.

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Did you set the allowed referers in your [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)? Click *credentials* in the left pane.

Comment: Yes, i have tried almost everything, blank referer, * , localhost, file://*, etc.. Neither a html file on my desktop works. Only work if i open the file via webserver like http://localhost:8080/map.html

Comment: Where does it NOT work from?

Comment: My problem is on phonegap app. I just have mentioned desktop because seems that is the same problem, lack of an http server to google know from where is the request.

Comment: You mean you are working on local?

Comment: You mentioned localhost. You can't add an API key to an app that runs on your localhost, emulator, etc.

Comment: ok, what i need to do to make google maps javascript api v3 work on phonegap app with an API KEY, being that there is no server on phonegap, it is as if it were local.

Comment: Hi Thyago, any solution since this old post ? Thanks :)